# How do I save a new user input considering I can't f.write() a function (I guess?)

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and basically, I just want to save what the user has input to a text file but I can't figure out the code to save it since I got an error that said "TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)".

```
#menu
def optionMenu():
    print("""
Hello! Welcome to Rainbow Bookstore.
Input a number if you are a/an:
[1] New user
[2] Staff
[3] Exit
""")
    choiceMenu = int(input("Choice: "))

    return choiceMenu


#main
import menu
import display

s = menu.optionMenu()
if (s == 1):
    f = open("newmember.txt", "a")
    
    menu.userInput()
    display.displayUser()
    print("Data is saved. Thank you!")
    f.close()


#display
import menu

r = menu.userInput()

def displayUser():
    name = input("Your name: ")
    age = input("Your age: ")
    email = input("Email: ")

    return name, age, email
```

[image: main, menu and display modules]

Comment: Please provide actual code, not screenshots - as there is no way to copy run and debug an image.

Comment: Convert the data you want to save to a string, e.g. CSV format, then use file.write.  Documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

The 'write' function takes only a single parameter as input, so if you are trying to pass multiple values it will give an error.

You can store the values returned by displayUser function and parse into a string which can be used for storing into a file.

```
f = open("newmember.txt", "a")
menu.userInput()
name, age, email = display.displayUser()
msg = f"Name: {name}\nAge: {age}\nEmail: {email}\n"
f.write(msg)
f.close()
```

If you want to use it for storing multiple entries of data and read it, it might be better to use json or csv format.
Below is an example for json format.

```
import json
def read():
    # returns a list of user dict
    path = r"your_file_path"
    f = open(path, "r")
    msg = f.read()
    f.close()
    return json.loads(msg)

def write(user_list):
    # user_list is a list of user dict
    path = r"your_file_path"
    f = open(path, "w")
    f.write(json.dumps(user_list))
    f.close()

name, age, email = display.displayUser()
# construct a dict for writing in the file.
user = {"name": name, "age": age, "email": email}
users_list = read()
user_list.append(user)
write(user_list)
print("Data is saved. Thank you!")
```